# GWT null has no properties

Tags: gwt, internationalization, null

I have an issue when I compile the user interface, when i add a method messages.usuario(), Firebug show the error : TypeError: null has no properties
lblUsuario = new Label_2(null.nullMethod()); this is the code of my class :

```
    public class AdministradorMVP implements EntryPoint {


private MessageConstants messages;

@Inject
public void setMensajes(MessageConstants mensajes) {
    this.messages = mensajes;
}


private final MyWidgetGinjector injector = GWT.create(MyWidgetGinjector.class);



private Place defaultPlace = new SignInPlace("Admin");
private SimplePanel appWidget = new SimplePanel();

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */



Label lblUsuario = new Label(messages.usuario());
Label lblNombre = new Label(messages.nombre());
```

so I can't find the source of the problem, thank you

Comment: The problem is somewhere with your dependency injection (I assume you use gin /guice or something similar). Please add the setup code for the injection.

Comment: I'm new in the world of J2EE, so excuse me ^^ ... so the setup is the configuration in pom.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I'm missing the 'boostrap the injection' (see [JavaDoc of Ginjector](http://google-gin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/gwt/inject/client/Ginjector.html)). In other words, you need to trigger the initial inject to take place. Creating `MyWidgetGinjector` is not enough.

One solution is to add a method `void inject(AdministradorMVP entryPoint);` to the interface `MyWidgetGinjector` and in the class `AdministradorMVP` in `onModuleLoad` call as (one of) the first statements: `injector.inject(this);`.

Answer (score 2):

The GWT compiler generates `null.nullMethod()` whenever it can statically determine that a particular method is always called on a `null` reference. In this case, `messages` has been determined to always be `null` (either `setMensajes` is called with a `null` value or it's not called at all), so `messages.usuario()` would always throw a `NullPointerException`, and this is translated into a `null.nullMethod()` in the generated JavaScript code.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the problem, but in our case, usuario() is declared in class MessageConstants with tho code : 

        public interface MessageConstants extends Constants {

 String usuario();

and in MessageConstants_ca.properties we have : 

       usuario=Usuari

so why this return null ? & thank u for u'r response :)

Comment: See the answer from Hilbrand: as a consequence, `setMensajes` is never called, so `this.messages` is never assigned and always `null`, hence `messages.usuario()` would always throw a `NullPointerException`.